what does temenos mean?
what is temenos in the below:

To be in a body, for a theurgist,
was to have a place in this temenos,
and even union with the gods was not impossible for those whose embodiment was properly consecrated.

(Theurgy and the soul - Gregory Shaw)

Welcome to SE. According to Liddell and Scott's dictionary of ancient Greek, temenos means 1 - a piece of land cut off, assigned as a domain to kings and chiefs, and 2 - a piece of land dedicated to a god, the sacred precincts.

See τέμενος.

@LudwigV, hallowed grounds? Now I don't know why the butt bone is called sacrum.
